Error by running migrations with sqlite, typeorm and nestjs
I am facing the following errors with my project in Nestjs by running a migration with TypeORM.
npx typeorm migration:run -d ./ormconfig.js
Error during migration run:
/Users/pablo/Documents/git-projects/pokemon-battle/backend/src/database/migrations/1714397133472-MigrationPokemon.ts:1
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner, Table } from 'typeorm';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I don't understand something because the only code that has to use "require" and "module.exports" should be ormconfig.js
This is my code from the migration itself:
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner, Table } from 'typeorm';
import { Pokemon } from '../../model/pokemon.entity';
import * as jsonPokemon from '../data/pokemon.json';

//... rest of code


and this is my ormconfig.js
const { DataSource } = require('typeorm');

const dataSource = new DataSource({
  type: 'sqlite',
  database: './src/database/database.sqlite',
  entities: [],
  migrations: ['./src/database/migrations/*.ts'],
  synchronize: true, // Not recommended for production
});

module.exports = { dataSource };

Any ideas will be welcome.

The solution was to point to /src instead of /dist
Now it is working and the migration finished outstandingly.

The solution was to point to /src instead of /dist. Now it is working and the migration finished outstandingly
